# checking value of variable with respect to time in UPPAAL

Tags: properties, uppaal

I want to write this statement in property "If input at time t is 0 and input at time t+1 is 1 then system reset will be one " 
I am writing it like this,

xin(t)==0 && xin(t+1)==1 --> reset==1.

but it is showing error "function expected". 
how can i write a function .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `t` is a clock and `xin` is a variable, then try this as a query:

```
t==0 && xin==0 --> t==1 && xin==1 imply reset==1
```